GTM custom tag template - getCookieValues API always returns empty
I have a custom GTM tag template in which I try to use the getCookieValues API by specifying the cookie name.
I can see that the cookie exists on the website and has a value.   But when I run the template code, getCookieValues always gives me empty value.   I have the appropriate permission set for reading 'any cookies'.
Can someone please help?
This is the template code snippet for getting the cookie value:
const cookieName = 'test_cookie';

const consentStr = queryPermission('get_cookies', cookieName) ? getCookieValues(cookieName, true)[0] : undefined;
log('consentstr='+consentStr);

